# Make file available at route Angular 7

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I'm facing a problem I don't know how to resolve.

I'm trying to integrate my website with Apple Pay using Stripe's PaymentRequest. However, I'm having trouble with one of their [requisites](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#verifying-your-domain-with-apple-pay). I don't know how to make that file available at the route

```
https://exampledomain.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association
```

Can somebody help with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to move some static files to build paths you can use `angular.json` for example:

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    ...
    "#project_name#": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        ...
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "./build/path/to/project-root/",
            ...
            "assets": [ { "glob": "*", "input": "./src/static", "output": "." },
...
```

This would move files inside `./src/static` folder to `build/path/to/project-root/` the output path depends on some build configuration like `--output-path` 
and maybe something else.

Answer (score 15):

Exact example for OP's question,

**Step 1**: Create folder in `src` names `.well-known`

**Step 2**: Add `apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association` file inside `.well-known` folder

**Step 3**: Add 2 lines in `angular.json` assets

```
"src/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association",
{ "glob": "apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association", "input": "src/.well-known/", "output": "/" },
```

The final `assets` will look something like this,

```
"assets": [
              "src/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association",
              { "glob": "apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association", "input": "src/.well-known/", "output": "/" },
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
```

Now, You should be able to access the file on: `http://localhost:4200/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`

Comment: If running this on a docker container. Make sure you build it again for the changes to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Not using angular. Done it accessing my AWS dashboard and creating there the file. Just in case it helps someone else :)

Comment: you can also use angular.json assets configuration for defining some static files

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: for example `"build": { "options": { "assets": [ { "glob": "*", "input": "./src/static", "output": "." },...],` should emit everything from `src/static` folder to build root or if im wrong use `output` to modify where all files are moved

Comment: @BalB Can you elaborate on your process using AWS?

Comment: @MadhavanSundararaj I cannot remember and cannot access, since I left the company where I was doing that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it on the hosting directly. In my case, my Angular app is hosted on AWS S3 bucket.

First, create a .well-known folder and upload the file apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt in S3 bucket.

Second, go to Edit Static Website hosting setting. Set the value to .well-known under Index document section.