# How to preview a static file in my project using Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 8, in my project I have a folder with the release notes in pdf, I want to preview the pdf in my browser (native chrome pdf viewer).

Do I need to configure anything in the router?

The file is in the angular project, trying locally for now.

```html
<a href="./release_notes/ReleaseNotes-Version_1.0.38.pdf" target="_blank">Release Notes</a>
```

When I click a link with the url to my static file, the router shouts there is no route with that name.

Comment: You need to setup path to your release notes in angular.json assets check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670618/make-file-available-at-route-angular-7/56701792#56701792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular Dev Server will send a response for non asset paths with the `index.html`. So if you click that path it will open your Angular app and the Angular router will try to find a route for that path.

Since you want to view a static file, you can register your release notes folder as an asset to the `angular.json`, and setup a rewrite handler on the production server. By registering the folder as an asset, it'll be included when you build the app. Example:

**angular.json**

Find the build options on your `angular.json` and change the assets to something like this:

```
{
  "assets: [
    "src/assets",
    "src/release_notes"
  ]
}
```

**Production Server**

You can try to serve your `dist` folder using `superstatic` server and add this configuration to `superstatic.json` file on the project's root folder. The server will only send a response with `index.html` only if there is no matching file/folder with the requested path. You can install `superstatic` via npm with command: `npm install -g superstatic`.

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

Start the server with command:

```sh
superstatic ./dist/your-app-name
```

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you a lot! is there anyway to make it work locally? after running ng serve...

Comment: Thank you so much, we will think in a work around so we can access the documents in development, still will test your solution and will accept it once it's working. Thanks again!

Comment: @LuigiCordobaGranera sorry for late reply. That's should work locally too. You can just use absolute path for the `href`. For example: `<a href="/release_notes/v1.0.0.pdf" target="_blank">v1.0.0</a>`.